# TCPDF Image horizontal position not working

Tags: php, tcpdf

When creating a PDF in PHP (with [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)), I'm trying to position an image in the header, a small distance to the right of the left margin. However, the $x parameter is being completely ignored.

```
$img = file_get_contents('logo.png');
$pdf->Image('@'.$img,50,15,35,0,'PNG','','N',false,300,'L',false,false,0,false,false,false,false,[]);
```

The second parameter, 50, may as well be 0, 50 or 400: the image just won't move. If I change the 'L' for 'C', it goes to the middle of the page, but that's not what I want.

Am I missing something, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a fitbox before, then it will respect the X placing.

```
$img =file_get_contents('logo.png');
$fitbox = 'LT';
$pdf->Image('@'.$img,50,15,35,0,'PNG','','N',false,300,'L',false,false,0,$fitbox,false,false,false,[]);
```

Comment: It's not working. With $x as 0, 50 or 500, the image simply won't move.

Comment: Sorry if it didn't work. I came to your question facing the same problem, after adding the fitbox it worked.
My actual code was the following:
     if(file_exists("$my_path/rsrc/flags/". strtolower($sender_place['country_code']) . ".png")){
          $fitbox = "LT";
          $pdf->Image("$my_path/rsrc/flags/". strtolower($sender_place['country_code']) . ".png",95,70.5,15,7.5,"PNG","","L",true,300,"T",false,false,1,$fitbox);
      }

Comment: It seems you change the position of 'L' and 'T'? $align only accepts one of T, M, B or N. $palign only accepts one of L, C, R or empty string.

Comment: You're right, so it does nothing. Tried to give it M C and it totally displaced the element, still horizontal move was working, except it was using the original image size as box size. Changed back to empty char.